# iOS Development - What goes in View vs. View Controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I am just starting out iOS development, and I'm curious to see what the proper implementation of the view and view controllers are.

For example, I made a simple TicTacToe game with UIImageView's and UITapGestureRecognizer's. I used an outlet collection array, and then added gesture recognizers to each. I understand for something this simple following MVC is not crucial, but I want to learn it correctly. The outlets should technically be in the view, and I am adding UIGestureRecognizers to each in the view with the target object being my ViewController and the action being a function in my ViewController. However, when I do this my program crashes.

This version just adds an x to the UIImage touched:

```
import UIKit

class TTTView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            // add gesture recognizers to all spots on board
            for index in 0..<board.count {
                let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: "ViewController", action: "spotPressed:")
                board[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var board: [UIImageView]!
}
```

and my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var x = UIImage(named: "x")
    // executed when spot is tapped
    func spotPressed(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let fieldTapped = recognizer.view as UIImageView
        fieldTapped.image = x // implement with protocol

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
}
```

This code crashes with the error:

```
2015-04-02 11:17:41.761 TTTv4[11273:356731] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TTTv4.ViewController 0x7fc7d3f0e210> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key board.
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

This is not the same at all as the linked answer. This is in Swift and the error comes from a completely different function that happens to be trying to access a different view controller.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with what language your code is in; you have your class set incorrectly in IB. The answer at the other question correctly solves your problem.